# "struct" before already-declared struct

Tags: c, struct

I am still new in C. I know you can just use the already-declared `struct` as new data type such as `int`, `double`, etc. However, I encounter a `struct` written like this:

```
struct AdjListNode
{
    int dest;
    int weight;
    struct AdjListNode* next;
};
```

In this `struct`, the data type of "next" pointer is `struct AdjListNode*`. What does `struct` have to do with the already-declared `AdjListNode*`? Thanks!

Comment: It's for a linked list.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643987/structure-in-c-for-linked-list

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: It is a pointer to an Instance of the struct like this one, can be self as well.
In this particular example it seems like a linked list, so the next will point to the next struct in chain...

Comment: `AdjListNode` is not a data type.  It's a struct tag.  `struct AdjListNode` is the actual data type.  `struct AdjListNode *next;` declares `next` to be a pointer to a `struct AdjListNode`.

Comment: As far as your code goes, `struct AdjListNode` is the only valid way to refer to that structure.  It's only in C++ that you would be able to refer to the structure as simply `AdjListNode`.  In plain-old-C you need a `typedef` before you can refer to the structure without the `struct` keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does struct have to do with the already-declared AdjListNode*?

The answer is that the `c` syntax requires it.

You do **not** get a type `AdjListNode` by writing `struct AdjListNode { ... };`

`AdjListNode` is a struct tag and you always have to use `struct AdjListNode` when declaring variables.

See this simple example (without pointer inside the struct):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct sSomeName
{
    int x;
};

int main(void) {
    struct sSomeName var;    // OK, variable of type struct sSomeName 
    struct sSomeName* pVar;  // OK, pointer to variable of type struct sSomeName 

    // sSomeName var2;       // ERROR: unknown type name 'sSomeName'

    var.x = 5;
    pVar = &var;

    printf("%d\n", pVar->x);
    return 0;
}
```

So if you want to add a pointer inside the `struct`, you must write `struct sSomeName` just as you have to do inside `main`, i.e. like:

```
struct sSomeName
{
    int x;
    struct sSomeName* p;
};
```

**Using typedef**

If you want a type named `AdjListNode` you must use `typedef`.

A `typedef` example could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct sSomeName sSomeName;

struct sSomeName
{
    int x;
    sSomeName* p;
};

int main(void) {
    sSomeName var;
    sSomeName* pVar;

    var.x = 5;
    var.p = NULL;
    pVar = &var;

    printf("%d\n", pVar->x);
    printf("%p\n", (void*)pVar->p);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here with that declaration pointer to structure is declared. This is basically used for implementing linked list or for other data structures like tree.

It does'nt mean that struct is re-declared. It is similar to declare a struct variable.

Answer (score 0):

The structure is created as follows: `typedef struct AdjListNode`. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct AdjListNode
{
    int dest;
    int weight;
    struct AdjListNode* next;
}AdjListNode;


typedef struct Nodo{
    char *nombre;
    int *edad;
    struct Nodo *siguiente;
}Nodo;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    AdjListNode *nodo=malloc(sizeof(AdjListNode));
    nodo->dest=1;
    nodo->weight=2;
    nodo->next=NULL;
    printf("Nodo-->dest: %d", nodo->dest);
    free(nodo);
}
```

Comment: There is no `typedef` in the question, so you've gone off at something of a tangent to the question, I think.  Also, the typedef line in the first sentence is incomplete.